# Simplex using Python: How to set up the code

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

**Constraints**:

5x1 + 6x2 >= 95

18x1 - 9x2 >= 189

x1 + x2 <= 45

x1, x2 >= 0

**Maximize:**

z = 15x1 + 15x2

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


c = [-15,-15]
A = [[-5,-6], [-18,9],[1,1]]
b = [-95,-189,45]
x0_bounds = (0,None)
x1_bounds = (0,None)


from scipy.optimize import linprog
# Solve the problem by Simplex method in Optimization
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b,  bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds), method='simplex', options={"disp": True})
print(res)
```

This is returning:

Max of 675 occurring at x1 = 22, x2= 23

However the answer is max = 675 occurring at (x1,x2) = (22,23) & (45,0)

So it is not returning the second value for x1 and x2

Comment: All points on `x1 + x2 = 45` between `(22,23)` and `(45,0)` have this same mimimum.  The objective function has the same 1:1 slope as this constraint.

Comment: LP solvers only report one point.